# How do I send and process one to many request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with an inventory system and I'm in the part where the cashier adds items to be purchased. So the tables i'm working with in that particular module is sales and sale_items. So the relationship is 1 sale has many sale_items.

So my question is. How can I send a request in one go without using ajax. Currently I'm using ajax but my controller requires authentication. I turned off the authentication to make the ajax request work. Below is the sample request body that I wanna send without ajax.

```
sales{
   date_sold: 04/01/2019,
   discount: 2000,
   branch_id
   sales_item: 
   {
      product_id: 1,
      quantity: 20,
      unit_price: 200
   },
   {
      product_id: 2,
      quantity: 40,
      unit_price: 100
   },
   {
      product_id: 3,
      quantity: 50,
      unit_price: 300
   }
}
```

I want to insert these data to the sales and sales_item tables respectively. How do I process it in laravel?

Comment: You can still use ajax with authentication tho.

Comment: i need to get the current logged in user in the controller and the Auth::user() returns null without the auth middleware.

Comment: I forgot to mention. My app is not an SPA. I only need the api for that page. All is serve purely by laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Create a relationships between sales and sale_items and you may do like this code below in your controller.

```
$sale = App\Sale::Find($id);

$saleItems = collection([..]);

foreach($saleItems as $item)  { 
    $sale->saleItems()->create([
         'sale_id' => $item->sale_id, 
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Anyway sir, how can i construct the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table that defines the relationship between the sale and the items.
So you would have a sale_item_rel where it would contain the id of the sale and the id of the items.
When you get the request assuming you are sending the ids of the item and the sale in an array.
Then you just need to insert the id of the sale and the id of the item into the table. Also checking that the item exists.

Assuming this is what you meant Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have the tables and its relationship. I just need the logic both in frontend and backend. The logic in backend is already answered by jesus erwin suarez. Do you know the mark up for the form?

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is only authentication, why not use laravel passport to handle API authentication?.

this frontend without ajax.

```
<form action="{{route('your route')}}" method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}
<input type="date" name="date_sold">
<input type="integer" name="discount">
<select name="branch_id" id="">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value=""></option>
</select>
<!--  sales item -->
<select name="product_id[]" id="">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value=""></option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="">
<input type="number" name="unit_prize[]">
</form>
```

and on request, you will get sale_items as array data.

Comment: My login is the default laravel auth. Can i integrate it with passport?